# Flutter Background Service does not work on android 8

Tags: android, flutter, background-service, flutter-background

Service works properly on Android 9 and above facing issues on devices 8<=
Notification disappears in some duration and location services stops

I have also disabled battery optimization but it did not work

Is there anyway to perform background services on android 8 and below
**My Code**

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {

  // Only available for flutter 3.0.0 and later
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  final DatabaseService databaseService = DatabaseService();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
  final stream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
    locationSettings: const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        timeLimit: Duration(seconds: 10)
    ),
  ).listen((position) async {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Position : $position');
    }
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notificationId,
      'COOL SERVICE',
      position.latitude.toString() + position.longitude.toString() + DateTime.now().toString(),
      const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          notificationChannelId,
          'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
          icon: 'ic_bg_service_small',
          ongoing: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
    var now  = DateTime.now();
    //Month is capital MM to distinct 'minute and month'
    //HH means 24 hour format
    var formatter  = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    var route = MapRoute(createdAt:formatter.format(now),latitude: position.latitude, longitude: position.longitude);
    try {
      await databaseService.insertBreed(route);
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
  }});
}
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to make Background services work on Android Devices less than 9. I had to disable AllBatteryOptimzation for current app.

Do this

DisableBatteryOptimization.showDisableAllOptimizationsSettings('App Process', 'Enable App Battery Usage', 'Battery Optimization', 'Enable process');

Instead of this

DisableBatteryOptimization.showDisableBatteryOptimizationSettings();